# how to remove and add character/integer in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

```
8/3/2015,1,F&B,L,05_>50 yrs,08_> 50 mio,02_100-<500rb,000129
```

Actually what i wanna do is pre-processing this input, But i don't know how to process it. The problem is i would like to remove the 05_ , 08_ , 02_ and adding new integers like "0858" in front of 000129 using python language. is there any guidance to solve it?

This is the desired output:

```
8/3/2015,1,F&B,L,>50 yrs,> 50 mio,100-<500rb,085800000129
```

Comment: what's the logic behind this? Is `**` really exists on your input?

Comment: no it doesn't, i just want to mark parts of input that want to be delete. let me correct the question.

Comment: @Brandon please show some desired output sample.

Comment: use `re` (regular expresions) to find "two digits and _" and remove it. use `string.rindex(",") to find last comma and add text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `0858` after last comma

```
data = "8/3/2015,1,F&B,L,05_>50 yrs,08_> 50 mio,02_100-<500rb,000129"

last = data.rfind(",")
if last > -1:
    data = data[:last+1] + "0858" + data[last+1:]
```

Looking for `_` and removing two chars before

```
while True:
    pos = data.find('_')
    if pos < 0:
        break
    data = data[:pos-2] + data[pos+1:]
```

It could be done better. I leave it to you :)